# Can any path segments of a URI have a query component?

Tags: url, syntax, uri, rfc, rfc2396

According to the [Section 3.3, **Path Component** of **RFC2396** - Uniform Resource Identifiers](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396#section-3.3),

> The path may consist of a sequence of path segments separated by a single slash "/" character.  Within a path segment, the characters "/", ";", "=", and "?" are reserved.  Each path segment may include a sequence of parameters, indicated by the semicolon ";" character.  The parameters are not significant to the parsing of relative references.

However, I have never seen a URL with a query parameters in any segment other than the final one.  So, I am not sure if I am reading this correctly.

Is `http://www.url.com/segment1?seg1param1=val1/page.html?pageparam1=val2` a valid URL?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What the RFC is referring to is something like this:

```
http://www.example.com/foo/bar;param=value/baz.html
```

That could be interpreted as the path `/foo/bar/baz.html` with the parameter `param=value` to the `bar` segment. No question marks are used.

Note that RFC 2396 has been obsoleted by [RFC 3986](ftp://ftp.rfc-editor.org/in-notes/rfc3986.txt), which omits specification of segment-specific parameters in favor of a general note that implementations can (and do) do different things to embed segment-specific parameters:

> Aside from dot-segments in hierarchical paths, a path segment is
>     considered opaque by the generic syntax.  URI producing applications
>     often use the reserved characters allowed in a segment to delimit
>     scheme-specific or dereference-handler-specific subcomponents.  For
>     example, the semicolon (";") and equals ("=") reserved characters are
>     often used to delimit parameters and parameter values applicable to
>     that segment.  The comma (",") reserved character is often used for
>     similar purposes.  For example, one URI producer might use a segment
>     such as "name;v=1.1" to indicate a reference to version 1.1 of
>     "name", whereas another might use a segment such as "name,1.1" to
>     indicate the same.  Parameter types may be defined by scheme-specific
>     semantics, but in most cases the syntax of a parameter is specific to
>     the implementation of the URI's dereferencing algorithm.

Comment: I did not know that the spec had been obsoleted.  I'm going to review the updated one now.

Comment: Appendix D2 "Modifications" was also especially helpful...  Thanks so much, I never would have figured this out just by reading the obsoleted spec

Comment: if question marks are used, it then becomes a query?

Answer (score 1):

When you look at the grammar which is just below, it is written:

> ```
>   path          = [ abs_path | opaque_part ]
>
>   path_segments = segment *( "/" segment )
>   segment       = *pchar *( ";" param )
>   param         = *pchar
>
>   pchar         = unreserved | escaped |
>                   ":" | "@" | "&" | "=" | "+" | "$" | ","
> ```

A segment is composed of pchar and param, param being itself a pchar.
When we continue to read, there is absolutely no "?" character in the pchar character components. So the parameters cannot have any "?", and there cannot be a "?" in segments.

So I agree with the answer of Edward Thomson, who says that "?" only delimit the query segment, and cannot be used inside a path.

Answer (score 0):

According to my reading of RFC 2396, **no**.  The `?` is a reserved character and serves only to delimit the query segment.  The `?` is not allowed in either the path or the query segment.

In your example, the first `?` marks the beginning of the query segment.  The second `?` is inside the query segment, and is disallowed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could do a get with that and most web servers would process it but I don't believe you would get the results you are expecting. That is the pageparam1=val2 would not evaluate.

If you want parameters like that you could always use the # symbol (as a lot of javascript based GUIs do now).